# How do I get data from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this snippet:

```
const slackProfiles = await Promise.all(

checkinsDetails.map(async ({ employeeEmail }) => {
    const employeeData = Employee.findOne({
      workEmail: employeeEmail,
    });

    console.log('employee ', employeeData);

    const slackId = employeeData ? employeeData.slackId : '';
```

When I log the employee data in my console, I am getting this kind of data:

```
employee  Query {
   _mongooseOptions: {},
   _transforms: [],
   _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
   _executionCount: 0,
   mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
      collection: null,
 opts:
  { bufferCommands: true,
    capped: false,
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
 name: 'employees',
 collectionName: 'employees',
 conn:
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Mongoose],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object],
    _readyState: 0,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: false,
    '$internalEmitter': [EventEmitter],
    _listening: false },
 queue: [],
 buffer: true,
 emitter:
  EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined } },
 model:
{ [Function: model]
 hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Map], _posts: [Map] },
 base:
  Mongoose {
    connections: [Array],
    models: [Object],
    modelSchemas: [Object],
    options: [Object],
    _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
    Schema: [Function],
    model: [Function],
    plugins: [Array] },
 modelName: 'Employee',
 ...
```

When I append `await` before `EMployee.findOne({})`, nothing is logged in the console. I have also tried

```
Employee.findOne({
      workEmail: employeeEmail,
    },(err,data)=>console.log("data",data);
```

but it does not output anything.

Answer (score 0):

What the `console.log` outputted is the query and not the results. Also, the callback format to fire the query at MongoDB from Node.js doesn't need await/async.

Following should work assuming that `Employee` is a collection object. Just avoid async/await in this scenario since callback function takes care of it.

```
Employee.findOne({
      workEmail: employeeEmail,
    },(err,data)=>console.log("data",data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this , i think this would work for you.

```
Employee.findOne({workEmail: employeeEmail}).then(err, result) {console.log(result)};
```

Comment: This should work, I think the problem is because the calls are being made from a child process

Comment: @MeshackMbuvi Did you able to solve your problem by this solutions

Answer (score 0):

Using Nodejs, express and MongoDB this the right way to get data from MongoDB with the help of JavaScript async/await.

```js
const request = async (req, res, next) => {
  let employeeData;
   try {
    employeeData = await Employee.findOne({workEmail: employeeEmail});
  } catch(err) { 
    return res.status(500).json("server error");
  }
}

console.log('employee', employeeData);
```