# Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field Mean Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-auto-increment

I have a collection created for maintaining `ticket_no`, for which document looks like this,

```
{
  id:"TICKET_ID",
  TICKET_NO:7
}
```

Now, when I try to findOneAndUpdate for a `ticket_id`, incrementing `TICKET_NO` by 1,

```
function get(){
     var ret = Sequence.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                query: { _id: 'TICKET_ID' },
                update: { $inc: { TICKET_NO: 1 } },
                new: true
            }
        );

        console.log(ret.TICKET_NO)
        return ret.TICKET_NO;
}
```

The function returns `null` value instead of `ticket no`

Comment: Hey there, did you salve to mongo? if it is returning null, maybe because the dataset is empty. Try something like `console(Sequence.find())`, and you will see all the documents before trying to get information from then, and make sure the document is saved.

Comment: I see you are printing the found document here `console.log(ret.TICKET_NO)`, what do you see?

Comment: `undefined`  is the result of `console.log(ret.TICKET_NO)`

Comment: dataset is not empty

Comment: Try logging `ret` instead of `ret.TICKET_NO`

Comment: getting `Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
..........`

Comment: can you let us know what you see when you do the comment `console(Sequence.find())`?

Comment: As you can see from your comment, something is wrong, it supposes to return something when you do `console.log(ret.TICKET_NO)`

Comment: please, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088835/how-do-i-get-data-from-mongodb

Comment: Are you using mongoose?? See here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html there is a difference in findOneAndUpdate

Comment: @JorgePires Mate, it's just a callback issue. Async/await will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting in ret is the findOneAndUpdate function object, not your actual document.

You need to listen to callback or use async/await for the value to be there,

Try one of these,

```
async function get(){
     var ret = await Sequence.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: 'TICKET_ID' },
          { $inc: { TICKET_NO: 1 } },
          { new: true }
     );

     console.log(ret.TICKET_NO) // now the ret is the doc you need
     return ret.TICKET_NO; // prints correctly
}
```

or,

```
function get(){
     Sequence.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: 'TICKET_ID' },
          { $inc: { TICKET_NO: 1 } },
          { new: true },
          function(err, ret) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err)
            } else {
              console.log(ret.TICKET_NO) //successful callback returns ret
            }
          });
     );
}
```

Comment: both methods are working.but TICKET_NO on the sequence collection is not updating always getting the same ticket no. Kindly help to resolve the same

Comment: What is the. TICKET_NO that you're getting?

Comment: `{id:"TICKET_ID",

TICKET_NO:7
}`.. ticket_no should be increment by 1 on each call.unfrtntly it is not updating on the database. so function always return 7 as ticket_no

Comment: Updated answer to reflect changes. Your options, i.e, `new: true` was not valid, as it was not in the correct format. The changes should work.